# Detect insertion with duplicate primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My api allows to attempt to add entitys with the same primary key. However I would like to filter DbUpdateException which occur for this reason because those would just pollute my Log files.
I use Sqlite for testing and Postgres in Production so I would like a way which could return me some exception kind to get the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with some extension class for the DbUpdateException still kinda hacky:

```
public static class UpdateExceptionHelper
{
    public enum UpdateExceptionKind
    {
        UniqueViolation,
        ForeignKeyViolation,
        Unknown
    }

    public static UpdateExceptionKind Kind(this DbUpdateException dbUpdateException)
    {
        var inner = dbUpdateException.InnerException;
        switch (inner)
        {
            case null:
                return UpdateExceptionKind.Unknown;
            case SqliteException sqlite:
                return sqlite.Kind();
            case PostgresException postgres:
                return postgres.Kind();
            default:
                throw new Exception($"Unsupported Database Provider with Exception Type: {inner.GetType().Name}");


        }
    }

    private static UpdateExceptionKind Kind(this PostgresException e)
    {
        const string UNIQUE_VIOLATION = "23505";
        const  string FOREIGN_KEY_VIOLATION = "23503";

        switch (e.SqlState)
        {
            case UNIQUE_VIOLATION:
                return UpdateExceptionKind.UniqueViolation;
            case FOREIGN_KEY_VIOLATION:
                return UpdateExceptionKind.ForeignKeyViolation;
            default:
                return UpdateExceptionKind.Unknown;
        }
    }

    private static UpdateExceptionKind Kind(this SqliteException e)
    {
        const int SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE = 2067;
        const int SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY = 1555;
        const int SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY = 787;

        switch (e.SqliteExtendedErrorCode)
        {
            case SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY:
            case SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE:
                return UpdateExceptionKind.UniqueViolation;
            case SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY:
                return UpdateExceptionKind.ForeignKeyViolation;
            default:
                return UpdateExceptionKind.Unknown;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sql Server you can use [`SqlException.Number`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number(v=vs.110).aspx) property of an inner exception of `DbUpdateException` of to identify the *Violation of PRIMARY KEY* error. For *Violation of PRIMARY KEY*  `SqlException.Number = 2627`.
You can try something like this:

```
try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    if (ex.InnerException is SqlException sqlEx && sqlEx.Number == 2627)
    {
    }
}
```

I believe for `Sqlite` and `Postgres` the idea should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the SQL Server, I would suggest filtering [SqlException.Number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number(v=vs.110).aspx) 2601 and 2627 to catch primary key/unique key constraint violations:

- 2601: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '%.*ls' with unique
  index '%.*ls'. The duplicate key value is %ls.
- 2627: Violation of %ls  constraint '%.*ls'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '%.*ls'. The duplicate key value is %ls.

Sample Code:

```
try {
    using(var db = new DatabaseContext()) {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
catch(UpdateException ex) {
    var sqlException = ex.InnerException as SqlException;        
    if(sqlException != null && sqlException.Errors.OfType<SqlError>()
        .Any(se=>se.Number == 2601 || se.Number == 2627 /* primary key/unique key constraint violation */)) {            
        // handle duplicate
    }
}
```

---

Another approach is checking for duplicates before inserting.
To do so, make sure to run both actions in an atomic transaction to avoid concurrency issues. Otherwise, two or more transactions may try to insert a record with the same key.

Comment: SQL server alone doesn't help me. I'm aware that I can check the inner exception. I was hoping there would be some library which can map exceptions from multiple backends to some generic kind. Checking for duplicates before inserting is just awful performance-wise.

Comment: Note that `UpdateException` is a error class from EntityFramework and doesn't exist in .NET itself. Answer also casting the exception to `SqlException` which is .NET Exception class. Also it is not required to use slow LINQ statements, a simple `if` would do the same a lot faster